# Apply jquery function for an ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an issue.. the issue is jquery is not applying to a ajax content..
My jquery:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.mainWorkImage').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(200);
},
function() {
    $(this).find('.caption').stop(false,true).fadeOut(200);
});

});
```

Content : -

```
            echo "<div class=\"mainWorkImage\" projects=\"".$mainResult['category']."\"><a href=\"work.php?page=".$mainResult['id']."\"><img name=\"mainWorkImage\" src=\"".$mainResult['imageUrl']."\" width=\"212\" height=\"207\" alt=\"\"/><div class=\"caption\"><p>PROJECT NAME:</p><p>".$mainResult['projectName']."</p><br/><p>PROJECT TYPE:</p><p>".$mainResult['category']."</p></div></a></div>";
```

Whats happening here is i have a dropdown when the dropdown change the content will be fetched from DB using AJAX and displayed .. But the caption div is not displaying for the content loaded from AJAX . Please Help me . Thanks In Advance...

Comment: can u also paste the ajax part,i can't figure put only from the hover function.

Answer (score 1):

depending on your jquery version take a look http://api.jquery.com/on/
Alternative use the "live" handler.

The .hover() handler does not work, because the target does not exist at the time it is applied.

Answer (score 1):

you can either bind the functions on successful ajax load

i.e.

```
$.ajax{
url:
data:
    success(function){
     //put your bind elements here
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) api.

Comment: You're linking to the `.on()` documentation (which is good), although you talk about `.live()` (which is deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('body').delegate('.mainWorkImage','hover',function() {
    $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(200);
},
function() {
    $(this).find('.caption').stop(false,true).fadeOut(200);
});

});
```